# tinymce script conflict with mmportfolio uploading images function

Tags: php, javascript, joomla, mootools, tinymce

I have a problem with uploading form in mmportfolio joomla component, when I try to upload new image to a project it give me this error

> Component returned failure code: 0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.implementation]
>   http://localhost/site/plugins/editors/jce/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js?version=155
>   Line 1

when I disable the tiny mce editor it works fine

does any body can help me with this error , how can i FIX IT

thanks alot

Fadi Yousef

Comment: this looks like a broblem with the browser you use (which one?). i suggest you download the development version of tinymce and use tiny_mce_dev.js instead of tiny_mce.js this way you will get a more speaking error message